# FreeformPro Not Submitting After Upgrade

Tags: solspace-freeform

I have a site I inherited and did a big update on. All looked good until we tested the contact forms that use Freeform Pro and they aren't submitting.

EE 2.10.0
Latest versions of Structure/Publisher/FreeformPro.

Freeform code is:

```
{exp:freeform:form 
            form:class="form-horizontal" 
            form:id="freeform"
            form_name="contact" 
            form:action="{root_url}index.php/{publisher:current_language_code}/?ACT=50" 
            return="{root_url}index.php/{publisher:current_language_code}/{segment_1}/thank-you" 
            parse="inward" 
            ajax="yes"
            required="first_name|last_name|email"
            match="email"
            recipients="yes" 
            recipient1="***email_removed" 
            recipient2="***email_removed" 
            recipient_template="contact_form_notification"
        }
```

Originally the "ACT=50" was "ACT=42" - on a whim I looked at the exp_actions table and saw no entry there for 42 but Freeform had an action of 50 so I thought that might be the issue.

Googling around it looks like this is possibly .htaccess related.  Currently the site has:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(ACT=.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5})$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

When I try to submit the form the Chrome JS inspector shows:

```
`POST (**URL removed) /en/respond/contact-the-hope?ACT=50 404 (Not Found)
```

I threw a quick EE contact form in and it submits/sends email successfully.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong but that first line looks like it's saying:

"If the request DOES NOT include ACT=50 route it to index.php"

So I'd try removing that and see what happens.

Comment: No probs, sometimes hard to see these things. :)